Congruence in Number Theory - Linear congruence and incongruent solutions
I've already learned the theorem about solving the linear congruence $ax \equiv b \pmod{m}$. Now suppose I want to find the values of $t$ that make $x = 3t + 1$ incongruent mod $9$. I know that these $t$ values are $0, 1, 2$ since when $t = 3$, $x = 10 \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, which is the same as when $t = 0$. But how does this work? What is its relationship with that theorem about solving the linear congruence $ax \equiv b \pmod{m}$?
And moreover, could this become a theorem like the following?

(Maybe a theorem?) Let $x = at + b$ and $d = (a,m)$. Then $x$ has $d$ incongruent solutions mod $m$, which are obtained when $t = 0, 1, \ldots, d-1$?


$ 3x!+!1 \equiv  3t!+!1 \iff 3x \equiv 3t\iff x\equiv t\pmod{!3}\iff x\equiv t,t!+!3,t!+!6\pmod{9},$ by the Theorem. Is that what you seek? $\ \ $

Not really. Could you please check if the theorem I stated is correct? If so, how to prove it?
